# Date validation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-validation

I cannot allow future date in my form built in angularjs

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ngCloak ng-app="laurelMoney" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="userForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type='date' id="trandate" class="form-control" ng-model="trandate" required ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.trandate.$error }" />
      <p ng-show="userForm.trandate.$error" class="help-block">Transaction can't be in future</p>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" ng-click="submitForm()" type="submit">Add Transaction</a>
  </form>
```

And my javascript isÑ

```
angular.module('laurelMoney', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("trandate").setAttribute("max", today);
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

      if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
        alert('our form is amazing');
      } else {
        console.log("Error");
      }

    };
  });
```

This is working fine when the calendar pops up. Future dates are all disabled. but i am able to manually change it to a future date in the date input box.

System is allowing submit for future dates also. How to go about this??

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0KLSuWPdQf1LEHmx6iRh)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, from what I could understand from your question you're simply trying to throw a error message or disallow user to select a future date, is it right? So, here you go:

**Notes:**

1. Your `Angular` version in plunker is completely outdated, so it may not work as you expected;
2. `ngCloak` should be `ng-cloak`;
3. You should add *name* `attribute` in your `input` to validate it;
4. Also, you could use [`ngSubmit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) to submit form, instead of `ng-click`.
5. As pointed out in comments, you can disable `button` if the `form` is `invalid`, rather than make this check in `controller`;
6. Finally, to set a date as max date (in your case *today*), you just have to do the following: `$scope.max = new Date()` and call it in your view;

Here's an complete example:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('laurelMoney', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

  myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.max = new Date();
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="laurelMoney">
  <div ng-cloak ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="userForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.trandate.$error }">
        <input type="date" name="trandate" class="form-control" required max="{{max}}" ng-model="trandate">
        <p ng-if="userForm.trandate.$touched && userForm.trandate.$error.required" class="help-block">Transaction is required</p>
        <p ng-if="userForm.trandate.$error.date" class="help-block">Transaction should be a valid date</p>
        <p ng-if="userForm.trandate.$error.max" class="help-block">Transaction can't be in future</p>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Add Transaction</button>
    </form>
    <pre ng-bind="userForm.trandate.$error | json"></pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is a good code sample, though isn't your `ng-class` unnecessary? pretty sure you would get `.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-max` applied to the `input[date]` when it is invalid.

Comment: Well, yes, it was just a copy from the OP's plunker.

Comment: ah, right. Also, OP, you should probably have `ng-submit='userForm.$valid && submitForm()'` rather than checking form validity in the controller. Just keeps things all in one place. Additionally, instead of having a error logged to the console (which you're doing), you can prevent validation messages from being shown by doing `<div ng-if='userForm.$invalid && userForm.$submitted'>` if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DanPantry, good catch, I corrected the `ngClass` part and also used `ng-disabled` to change the *state* of button.